# how to store files path in a user record?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, multer

I am trying to upload files to store in a user database but its not getting stored.
This is my schema.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  file: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

<--This is my route.I am using multer to handle multiform data -->

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "public/upload",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

//Initialize Upload
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
}).single("file");

//Check File Type
function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  // Allowed extensions
  const fileTypes = /pdf/;

  //Check extensions
  const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

  //Check mime
  const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("Error:Pdf only");
  }
}

router.post("/user/:id/upload", async (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(_id);
    if (!user) {
      res.status(404).json({ msg: "No User Found" });
    }
    user.file = req.file;
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(req.file);
      }
```

I am only able to store the files in the public folder.Is there a way to store files for a particular user in db so that I can know this user uploaded this file?

Answer (score 0):

Multer doesn't save files directly in your database. It only stores them in your file disk system.

So instead of doing `user.file = req.file` you should save the `destination + filename` you created with multer in the database.

You're saving the filename as `file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)` in `"public/images"` but in your database you're just saving `req.file` which is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me tell you that it's not the best practice to `store` a `file` itself in a `db`. The best practice is to store `filepath` to `user's object` so that you can track that which `file` `uploaded` by which `user`.

Let say you have a route like

```
router.post("/", log, upload.fields([{ name: 'userFile' }]), fileUpload);
```

and in your `fileUpload` `function` just check if files is present, and if `file` is present then save `file's url` in the `db` like this

```
function fileUpload(req,res){
   const user;
   if (req.files['userFile']) {
      user.filePath = `public/upload/${req.files['userFile'][0].filename}`;
      
      const userObj = new User(user);
      userObj.save();
   }
}
```

I just gave a rough implementation to just give you an idea that how can you achieve that.